# Where to find last Debian Wheezy security upgrades?

Tags: debian, security, apt, package-management

My Debian Wheezy server shall be up-to-date with all latest security packages, so I've added in sources.list:

```
deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
```

But apt-get never made any upgrade within the last weeks.
OK, this depends from the installed packages, so I want to manually check what have beed released to what is installed.

Is there a website where I see a human readable list of all recent advisories for Wheezy similar to what is available for Jessie and Sid [here](https://www.debian.org/security/#DSAS)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using [Wheezy's LTS](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS/Wheezy), and your repository setup is correct. There aren't many updates, you can follow along on the [debian-lts-announce](https://lists.debian.org/debian-lts-announce/) mailing list; see the [archives for February](https://lists.debian.org/debian-lts-announce/2017/02/threads.html) for example.

You should read the [wiki page on using LTS](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS/Using); in particular, make sure you install the `debian-security-support` package. I don't think there's a central web page which lists all the DLAs in the same way as the page you linked to lists all the DSAs, but you *can* track security bugs on the [Wheezy security tracker](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/status/release/oldstable).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was exactly what I was looking for...